# Wait until Angular has finished processing a model change before accessing scope

Tags: angularjs, nested-sortable

I'm using angular-ui-tree to make a scorecard application that has a hierarchy of scorecard nodes. My scorecard nodes are persisted through a web service layer and have their own ID numbers to identify them.

In order to work with a scorecard node by ID, I implemented the following method:

```
// get a node scope by a Scorecard Node ID.
function getNodeScopeByNodeID(id, nodesScope) {
    nodesScope = nodesScope || getRootNodesScope().$nodesScope;

    var nodes = nodesScope.childNodes();
    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        var result;
        if (nodes[i].$modelValue.ID == id)
            result = nodes[i];
        else {
            var subScope = nodes[i].$childNodesScope;
            if (subScope) {
                result = getNodeScopeByNodeID(id, subScope);
            }
        }
        if (result)
            return result;
    }

    return undefined;
}
```

The details here aren't super important except to say that this method crawls the nested scopes that make up the tree until it finds a scope whose $modelValue (my scorecard node state) has the ID we're looking for. It works great, except when I do something like this:

```
// add a new objective node to the root of the scorecard.
$scope.newObjective = function () {
    var scope = getRootNodesScope();
    var rootArray = scope.$nodesScope.$modelValue;
    scorecardService.addObjective($scope.selectedScorecard, rootArray)
        .then(function (d) {
            rootArray.push(d);
            $scope.edit(getNodeScopeByNodeID(d.ID));
        })
        .catch(errorHandler);
}
```

Note the two lines in the "then" function. I'm asking my service to create a new node, and when I get it I'm pushing it into an array that is part of the model. I want my newly inserted node to immediately flip into "edit" mode (which reveals some form controls inside it.) But the call to getNodeScopeByNodeID immediately following the push fails. If I debug it it looks like the scope hasn't caught up with the model yet. I have one more node in my node array (model) than there are child scopes where I expect them to be.

I think I just have to give angular a chance to react to the model change before I start going through the scope to find what I'm looking for. How do I do that?

Comment: Have you tried `$timeout(function(){$scope.edit(getNodeScopeByNodeID(d.ID))});` (after injecting $timeout into the component)?

Comment: Hey Marc, interesting idea. The first try failed but when I added a 100ms delay it worked. I'm not confident that this will work all the time though - depending on the client machine and etc., angular might take more or less time. Is there no other function/event/feature I can use to execute the code at the "correct" time?